# Restrict a phone number input field to accept only 6 8 and 10 digit numbers

Tags: php, html

I have a phone number input field that looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="phone" maxlength="10" size="40" value="{$tmp.phone}"><>
```

Can I apply a code inside here? Or would I apply a function in an external .php file to do this?

What would the code look like?

I am new to all this coding stuff and need some help...

Comment: {$tmp.phone} should be $tmp->phone and value="<?=$tmp->phone?>". Use regex to check for phone numbers'limited digits and correct format given, e.g 001-----325---658-1231 is a correct phone number but is ill-formatted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new HTML5 attribute `pattern`. New browsers will not send the form until it is filled correct:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="phone" pattern="^[0-9]{6}|[0-9]{8}|[0-9]{10}$" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If a user is using an older browser, the attribute is ignored. In this case you still should check it as Daniel and Pheonix recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Even if get some way to put a check in HTML, always do validation on your server side. Client side Validations can always be by-passed.

in server side

```
$phone = $_GET['phone'];

if(!(strlen($phone)==6 ||strlen($phone)==8 ||strlen($phone)==10)){
  //Error
}
```

Comment: you make a good point about the server side validation.. however i have some problems using this code. The .php file for the html page that contains all the input fields including the phone number input is confusing. for the fields this is what it shows.

 $fieldset = $categ->getFieldset($_SESSION['category']);
 $cf=new fields('cf');
 $fields=$cf->getAll($fieldset);
 $smarty->assign("fields", $fields);
//_print_r($fields);

How can i use your code in this case? 
is it somehting like if $fields==$phone->Do this?

Answer (score 0):

For better user experience you can validate using javascript, and for security reasons is mandatory to use server side validation as Pheonix said.

```
<form id="form_id">
<input id="phone_id" type="text" />
<input type="submit" 
    onclick="if (document.getElementById('phone_id').value.length != 6 
                 && document.getElementById('phone_id').value.length!=8 
                 && document.getElementById('phone_id').value.length!=10) 
                 { 
                     alert('Error message...'); 
                     return false; 
                 }" />
</form>
```